# python pandas - drop rows by knowing the location (loc), but not the index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.dataframe with an integer index (sorted / unique), but not every value exists.
In this dataframe, I have identified some rows that need to be deleted.
In addition, however, all subsequent rows (always one for each identified index) also need to be deleted, but their index cannot be determined.
I have already identified the location of these rows and extended a (new) list of locations.
But now, I have to either remove all rows according to the location list or transform it back into an index list.

Here is an code example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#  build identifier columns
identifier_1 = pd.Series([True]*3, index=[1, 5, 9])
identifier_2 = pd.Series([True]*3, index=[3, 8, 11])

# build dataframe with index and data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'data':[0, 1, 3, 7, 8, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 25, 28, 29]
    }, index=np.arange(13))

# merge identifiert to dataframe
df = df.merge(identifier_1.rename('ident_1'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.merge(identifier_2.rename('ident_2'), how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

df = df.fillna(value=False)

# recude df to rows where ident_1 or ident_2 have True values
relev_df = df.loc[df["ident_1"] | df["ident_2"], :]

# create column criteria
relev_df['criteria'] = np.where(relev_df.ident_1, relev_df.data.diff(periods=-1), np.NaN)

criteria_value = -5

# get indexes where the criteria is not fullfilled and make a list of these indexes
index_ident1 = relev_df[relev_df['criteria'] < criteria_value].index
index_ident1 = [x for x in index_ident1]

# transform these indexes to a list of locations (by .loc)
loc_ident_1 = []
unique_index = relev_df.index
for idx in index_ident1:
    _loc = unique_index.get_loc(idx)
    loc_ident_1.extend((_loc, _loc + 1))
```

Result (sofar):

```
df:
data  ident_1  ident_2
0      0    False    False
1      1     True    False
2      3    False    False
3      7    False     True
4      8    False    False
5     12     True    False
6     13    False    False
7     15    False    False
8     16    False     True
9     18     True    False
10    25    False    False
11    28    False     True
12    29    False    False

relev_df:
data  ident_1  ident_2  criteria
1      1     True    False      -6.0
3      7    False     True       NaN
5     12     True    False      -4.0
8     16    False     True       NaN
9     18     True    False     -10.0
11    28    False     True       NaN
identified indexes:    [1, 9]
identified locations:  [0, 1, 4, 5]
```

HOW to delete the identified rows, stored in 'loc_ident_1'

Expected result:

```
result_df:
data  ident_1  ident_2  criteria
5     12     True    False      -4.0
8     16    False     True       NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer "*How to delete the identified rows, stored in 'loc_ident_1'*", slice the index and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
result_df = relev_df.drop(relev_df.index[loc_ident_1])
```

Note that a vectorial approach would be to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```
m = relev_df['criteria'] < criteria_value
result_df = relev_df[~(m|m.shift())]
```

Output:

```
   data  ident_1  ident_2  criteria
5    12     True    False      -4.0
8    16    False     True       NaN
```

Intermediates for the second approach:

```
    data  ident_1  ident_2  criteria      m m.shift()  ~(m|m.shift())
1      1     True    False      -6.0   True       NaN           False
3      7    False     True       NaN  False      True           False
5     12     True    False      -4.0  False     False            True
8     16    False     True       NaN  False     False            True
9     18     True    False     -10.0   True     False           False
11    28    False     True       NaN  False      True           False
```

Comment: Wow, it can be so simple if you take the right approach. boolean indexing with shift is the correct answer to my question.
Thank you very much for the super simple and fast answer.